# how to solve "javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException:" in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

Error:

```
May 27, 2017 2:39:48 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.0.Final}
May 27, 2017 2:39:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 27, 2017 2:39:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 27, 2017 2:39:49 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
May 27, 2017 2:39:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 27, 2017 2:39:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/db]
May 27, 2017 2:39:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
May 27, 2017 2:39:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
May 27, 2017 2:39:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
May 27, 2017 2:39:52 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
May 27, 2017 2:39:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
May 27, 2017 2:39:54 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Code:

```
pojo class


public class Testpojo {


    private int number;
     private String name;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}



main class

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;



public class TestMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Testpojo tp=new Testpojo();
        tp.setNumber(3);
        tp.setName("MEHUL1");

        try{

        SessionFactory ses=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session s1=ses.openSession();
        Transaction tr=s1.beginTransaction();
        s1.update(tp);
        tr.commit();
                }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/db</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

<mapping resource="Testpojo.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>


mapping file


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Testpojo" table="t">
 <id name="number" column="num">
 <generator class="native"></generator>
 </id>`enter code here`
 <property name="name" column="name"></property>
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

create one simple appliaction of hibernate with Testpojo.java ,Testpojo.hbm.xml,Testmain.java and hibernatecfg.xml.
how to solve "javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException:" in hibernate ?
add all jar file of hibernate but still found this `error.javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException`:

Comment: Welcome! Please revise your question. It is unclear what exactly your problem is and what you did to solve it so far. Can you reduce the code to the essential points?

Answer (score 1):

You got OptimisticLockException means some other transcation is already using that particular record.

Comment: your example is not sufficient, please provide more detail of method where you are doing CURD operation because  OptimisticLockException occurs when more than one operation happens on one particular record.